# Заполнение Регистра сведений данными из документа

Tags: 1с

Есть регистр, связан с документом. Документ состоит из табличной части, в таблице 5 столбцов.

1-является ссылочным и ссылается на привязанный справочник (он и выбран измерением). Остальные 4-3 ресурсы, а один-не нужен.

Вот **как организовать проведение всей таблицы (за исключением 1 столбца)
или что б в регистр вносилась вся таблица, и как избежать ошибки при проведении "запись с таким именем существует"**

Я не могу найти рабочих вариантов (либо не пойму куда вписывать то что скидывают).

Ниже предоставлен код движения в модуле дока. Еще при повторном проведении документа, данные на замещаются, а выдаёт ошибку что данные таким именем уже созданы.

(пояснение-категории затрат-измерение, так же называется и реквизит, который ссылается на справочник, описание категории-то же самое что и категории затрат, только строковый формат (ну прописывается для другой задачи)

```
Процедура ОбработкаПроведения(Отказ, Режим)
    //{{__КОНСТРУКТОР_ДВИЖЕНИЙ_РЕГИСТРОВ
    // Данный фрагмент построен конструктором.
    // При повторном использовании конструктора, внесенные вручную изменения будут утеряны!!!

    // регистр РегистрПлановРасходов
    Движения.РегистрПлановРасходов.Записывать = Истина;
    Для Каждого ТекСтрокаТаблица1 Из Таблица1 Цикл
        Движение = Движения.РегистрПлановРасходов.Добавить();
        Движение.Период = Дата;
        Движение.КатегорииЗатрат = ОписаниеКатегории;
        Движение.ОбщаяЗаявленнаяСтоимость = ОбщаяЗаявленнаяСтоимость;
        Движение.СредстваАНОИРИ = СредстваАНОИРИ;
        Движение.ПривлекаемыеСредства = ПривлекаемыеСредства;
    КонецЦикла;

    //}}__КОНСТРУКТОР_ДВИЖЕНИЙ_РЕГИСТРОВ
КонецПроцедуры
```

Comment: при попытке провести по этому коду повторно-выдаёт ошибку
  Запись с такими ключевыми полями существует! : РегистрПлановРасходов: 14.02.2023 12:00:00, План по категориям 000000003 от 14.02.2023 12:00:00,  (Регистр сведений: Регистр планов расходов; Номер строки: 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос самостоятельно,обнаружил ошибку что ссылался на запись реквизитов не табличных,а обычных(указанных в поле реквизитов).
Но если есть варианты, которые более оптимальны, буду крайне благодарен, если покажите и объясните.

Answer (score 0):

В регистре сведений есть Измерения, которые являются набором уникальных значений записи; Если в Регистре уже есть запись с некоторым значением измерений, повторное добавление записи с таким же значением Измерений, вызовет ошибку !

https://its.1c.ru/db/pubapplied/content/30/hdoc

```
Движения.РегистрПлановРасходов.Записывать = Истина;
Движения.РегистрПлановРасходов.Очистить();   // Желательно очищать движения
```